# Do I need to have an About page in my Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to submit my first app to the windows market place but while trying to find out the certification process I become confused if I need an about page (that contains support information) or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do need to include some information which is probably best to have on an about page. See [5.6.1 in certification requirments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> An app must include the app name, version information, and technical
>   support contact information that are easily discoverable.

If you use the location API you will need to have a privacy policy in the app or linked in the app ([requirement 2.7.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), also 2.7.4 is relevant):

> The privacy policy of your app must inform users about how location
>   data from the Location Service API is used and disclosed and the
>   controls that users have over the use and sharing of location data.
>   This can be hosted within or directly linked from the app. The privacy
>   policy must be accessible from your app at any time.

Same goes for if you upload pictures, contacts etc from the app (see [2.8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

Ofcourse this information does not require a dedicated about page, but as they write, should be easy to find for the user.

Comment: And if you have no support for a free about what do you put?

Comment: It is usually enough to just include an email address or website url where the user can get help somewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to spend to much time on your about page and still want it to look great, take a look at this opensource project!
http://ylad.codeplex.com/

It comes as a nuget, so easy to add in your wp7 project! http://nuget.org/packages/YLAD